# What is a difference between rollup_rate (avg) and rate in MetricsQL?

Tags: metricsql

As stated in title, what is a difference between `avg` from `rollup_rate()` and `rate()` in MetricsQL?

It is not clear to me from [the official documentation](https://victoriametrics.github.io/MetricsQL.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose we have a time series with the following samples on the duration `d`:

```
(v1, t1), (v2, t2), .... (vN, tN)`
```

Then the `rate(m[d])` at `tN` is calculated as `(vN - v1) / (tN - t1)`, while the `avg` returned from `rollup_rate(m[d])` is calculated as an average value for per-sample rates `(v2-v1)/(t2-t1)`, ..., `(vN - vNminus1) / (tN - tNminus1)`.